# In ConcurrentHashMap, What is the benefit of using scanAndLockForPut insted of direct lock() method to aquire the lock on perticular segment?

Tags: java, collections

In **ConcurrentHashMap**, I have below two queries? I have read javadoc comment written in **Segment** class's source, But could not understood it.

1. What is the functionality of  **scanAndLockForPut** method?
2. What is the benefit of using **scanAndLockForPut** instead of using lock() method to acquire the lock on particular segment?
3. from javadoc comment, I found that **scanAndLockForPut** is used to reduce cache misses..What is the cache misses and how this method reduce it ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The point of `scanAndLockForPut` is, more or less, to do something useful while waiting for the lock on the segment.  In particular, it starts checking whether or not the entry is already present, walking slowly through the hash bucket as it waits for the lock, and if it reaches the end of the bucket it creates a new entry for the value to go into.  (Additionally, walking through the hash bucket moves the entries we'll care about into cache, which means it'll be faster to look at them again after the lock is successfully acquired.)